# Add points or dots in specific positions of a line chart and adapt the tooltip accordingly with ggplotly()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I create the total data frame below with:

```
# Dummy data
data <- data.frame(
  int_end = as.Date("2017-06-14") - 0:364,
  users = runif(365) + seq(-140, 224)^2 / 10000,
  user_type=sample(c('active', 'inactive'), 365, replace = TRUE)
)

data2 <- data.frame(
  int_end = as.Date("2017-06-12") - 0:12,
  MP =sample(c('P', 'M'), 13, replace = TRUE),
  DESCRIPTION=sample(c('text1', 'text2','text3'), 13, replace = TRUE)
  
)
# merge two data frames by ID
total <- merge(data,data2,by="int_end",all = TRUE)
```

The I create a line chart with `ggplotly()`. What I want to achieve is add points or dots or bubbles in the line chart where there are data in the columns `MP` and `DESCRIPTION`. Also the tooltip at these points should also include `MP` and `DESCRIPTION` besides the other columns. In the rest of the points `MP` and `DESCRIPTION` ideally should not be displayed in the tooltip at all or at least be like `NAs`,like for example `DESCRIPTION:NA`

```
library(plotly)
plot <- total %>%
  ggplot(aes(int_end, users, color = user_type)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw() +
  #theme(legend.position = "none")+
  theme(legend.position = 'top')+
  labs(title = glue::glue("Number of Users over time."),
       subtitle = glue::glue("Interval window of days."),
       y = "", x = "")
ggplotly(plot)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved like so:

1. For the dots you could add a `geom_point` layer which you pass a filtered dataset including only observations with non missing `MP` or `DESCRIPTION`
2. The conditional tooltip could be achieved via the `text` aes. For convenience I create the tooltip text via  a separate function and add the tooltip texts as a new column to your dataset.

```
# merge two data frames by ID
total <- merge(data,data2,by="int_end",all = TRUE)

tooltip_text <- function(int_end, users, user_type, MP, DESCRIPTION) {
  text <- glue::glue("int_end: {int_end}", "<br>",
                     "users: {users}", "<br>",
                     "user_type: {user_type}")
  
  text <- ifelse(!is.na(MP), glue::glue("{text}<br>MP: {MP}"), text)
  text <- ifelse(!is.na(DESCRIPTION), glue::glue("{text}<br>DESCRIPTION: {DESCRIPTION}"), text)
  
  text
}
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

total <- mutate(total, text = tooltip_text(int_end, users, user_type, MP, DESCRIPTION))

plot <- total %>%
  ggplot(aes(int_end, users, color = user_type, group = user_type,
             text = text)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = filter(total, !is.na(MP) | !is.na(DESCRIPTION))) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = 'top')+
  labs(title = glue::glue("Number of Users over time."),
       subtitle = glue::glue("Interval window of days."),
       y = "", x = "")
ggplotly(plot, tooltip = "text")
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68167060/trying-to-add-dots-is-specific-points-of-line-chart-removed-the-lines plz check this based on your answer.only dots are dsiaplyed if the exist but no lines